# Common location for systemd unit files on Ubuntu and RHEL

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rhel, systemd

I would like to create a scripted install for a list of `Systemd` services. This installation should support both Ubuntu (starting with version 16.04) and RHEL/CentOS (starting with version 7.2)

I read [RHEL docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) and found three paths that I could store unit files in, these paths are:

- /usr/lib/systemd/system/
- /lib/systemd/system/
- /etc/systemd/system

What is the correct location for services that fulfills these criteria:

- Unit files are there for non-system level services (application specific services)
- No already existing OS level services are overwritten
- The location is identical on Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system` is the one, since `/usr/lib/systemd/system` is for units of installed packages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In default Red Hat distributions, `/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib`, but it appears those are different locations in Ubuntu.

[According to the systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` is designated to hold upstream unit files that would not be edited by users and instead be provided and updated via packages.

The `/etc/systemd/system` is designated as where user provided unit files would be.  Packages should not override or update anything in `/etc/systemd/system`.  You can also use `/etc/systemd/system` to override existing unit files.

So using `/etc/systemd/system` should be the most compatible between different distributions.